# Configuring IdentityServer 4 with Identity, combining services.AddAuthentication() and services.AddIdentity()

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

Using Identity Server 4, .NetCore2.0 and MS Identity with Implicit Flow/Grant Type;

I am not clear on the responsibilities of the the following as each specifically relates to validating/authorizing a bearer token.

I have the following Startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        ...
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
           .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
           {
               options.Authority = GetAuthentication().ApiURL;
               options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

               options.ApiName = "afapps";
           });

        // Below needed to inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
        // elsewhere in app as this happens to be the authORization server
        // as opposed to authENtication server.
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()                
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

If I omit the `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()...` in startup.  In controllers I can successfully use [Authorize] and my other custom `ActionFilters` shows `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` as `== true`.

However, after adding `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()...` to enable usage of Identity's `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`;  I now have to additionally add `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]` to each controller..

Is there a way to combine or arrange `services.AddAuthentication()` and `services.AddIdentity()` such that I do not have to specify `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]`?

Comment: Have you identified `Bearer` as your `DefaultScheme`? If not, I think that's why you have to specify it for the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: I migrated from .NetCore1.1 => .NetCore2 today and was getting a 404 not found..  Which led to seeing [this git issue](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/498).  I have tried quite a few ways to set AddAuthentication() with AddJwtBearer vs "Bearer."  TBH I need to spend more time understanding the options.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions)` override *after* `AddIdentity()` to set the options manually like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Bearer";
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Bearer";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Bearer";
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = "Bearer";
    });
```

You have to do this because the string override only sets the `DefaultScheme`, while `AddIdentity()` [sets the more specific options](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/85f8a49aef68bf9763cd9854ce1dd4a26a7c5d3c/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L66). `DefaultScheme` is only used as the fallback for all the others, as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

Comment: This solved it.  Thanks [@Mim-nim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3395956/mim-nim)!

Comment: This had me stumped for ages, it's worth noting you can specify the scheme in the `[Authorize]` attribute too (I think)